# pivot dataframe after groupby result with value_counts()

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot

I've tried a lot, but can't find the solution.

I run this code on my df:

```
df.groupby(df['Operatiejaar'])['ASA'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

This has the expected result:

```
Operatiejaar  ASA
2017          1.0    1523
              2.0    2658
              3.0     685
              4.0      28
2018          1.0    1357
              2.0    2749
              3.0     729
              4.0      26
2019          1.0    1505
              2.0    2770
              3.0     787
              4.0      27
              5.0       1
Name: ASA, dtype: int64
```

Now, I would like to pivot this to:

```
    ASA 1   ASA 2   ASA 3   ASA 4
Jaar                
2017    1523    2658    685     28
2018    1357    2749    729     26
2019    1505    2770    787     27
```

I made this pivot.df by hand now. My question is:
Based on the groupby code above: how can I pivot my result to the wanted df? I believe this must be able, but how.... By the way: the result of the groupby is a Series. With pd.DataFrame(df)
I've converted it to a DataFrame.

thanks!! greetings Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), then convert columns names to integers and last use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
s = df.groupby(df['Operatiejaar'])['ASA'].value_counts().sort_index()

df1 = s.unstack().rename(columns=int).add_prefix('ASA ')
```

If need only first 4 rows per groups add [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = s.groupby(level=0).head(4).unstack().rename(columns=int).add_prefix('ASA ')
```

Comment: thanks!! exactly the answer I needed!! I tried allready with unstack, but just couldn't get it right. You're a great help and I learned something again! greetings